# As3: removing programmatically added child on hit test gives error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest, removechild

I have tried removing programatically added movieclips when they collide with a certain object. When they do, they vanish. But after they have vanished, I get a #1009 error.

The error points at line 95, which is

```
if (this.x > stage.stageWidth + 2 - (stage.stageWidth - (this.width /2)) && this.x < stage.stageWidth - (this.width /2))"
```

And sometimes at 59, which is

```
if (this.x >= stage.stageWidth - 20)"
```

Why does it keep trying to run line 95 (and sometimes) 59? I removed the eventlistener.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    public class Worker extends MovieClip
    {

        private var _root:MovieClip;
        private var actualRange:Number;
        private var reachedGoal:Boolean = false;
        private var b:uint;
        private var destination:Number;
        private var goRight:Boolean = true;
        private var goNowhere:Boolean = true;
        private var yDir:Number;
        private var yNumber:Number;

            public function Worker()
            {
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
                //defining _root as the document root

                actualRange =(Math.floor(Math.random() * (520 - 80 + 1)) + 80);

                b = setInterval(startInc, 3000);
            }


        private function beginClass(event:Event):void{
            //defining _root as the document root
            _root = MovieClip(root);
        }

            private function loop(event:Event):void
            {
                if (this.hitTestObject(_root.killGun))
                {
                    {
                        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
                        _root.removeChild(this);
                    }
                }

                if (reachedGoal == true)
                {

                    if (goNowhere == true)
                        {
                            gotoAndStop(1);
                        }
//Boundaries
                    if (this.x <= 20)
                    {
                        goRight = true;
                        goNowhere = false;
                    }
                    if (this.x >= stage.stageWidth - 20)
                    {
                        goRight = false;
                        goNowhere = false;
                    }

                    if (this.y >= stage.stageHeight - 20)
                    {
                        yDir = 0
                    }

                    if (this.y <= 20)
                    {
                        yDir = 1
                    }
                }

//Intro walk
                if (reachedGoal == false)
                {
                    if (this.x < actualRange)
                        {
                            gotoAndStop(4);
                            this.x += 3
                        }   

                    if (this.x >= actualRange)
                        {
                            reachedGoal = true;
                            gotoAndStop(1);
                        }
                }


//Main walk
                if (this.x > stage.stageWidth + 2 - (stage.stageWidth - (this.width /2)) && this.x < stage.stageWidth - (this.width /2))
                {
                    if (goNowhere == false)
                    {
                            if (goRight == true)
                            {
                                this.x += 1;
                                gotoAndStop(2);

                                //Y value
                            }
                            if (goRight == false)
                            {
                                if (this.x < stage.stageWidth - this.width /2)
                                this.x -= 1
                                gotoAndStop(3);

                                //Y value

                                if (yNumber == 1)
                                {                                   
                                    if(yDir == 0)
                                    {
                                        this.y -= 1;
                                    }
                                    if (yDir == 1)
                                    {
                                        this.y += 1;
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                    }

                }


            }


            //Timer functions
            private function completePlay()
            {
                clearInterval(b);
            }

            private function startInc()
            {   
                    var moveNumber:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);

                    if (moveNumber == 1)
                    {
                        destination = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);   
                        yDir = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
                        yNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

                        goRight = true;
                        goNowhere = false;
                    }

                    else if (moveNumber == 2)
                    {   
                        destination = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);       
                        yDir = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
                        yNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

                        goRight = false;
                        goNowhere = false;
                        gotoAndStop(3);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        goNowhere = true;
                    }

            }           


//End

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happening because you're removing the `eventListener` within the `eventListener`'s function and your removing the object from it's parent and still processing data that the object no longer contains or has been nullified. You should add a `boolean` to tell if the `hitTest` has occured and then not process any more of the loop. For instance:

```
private function loop(event:Event):void
    {
    var objectHit:Boolean = false;

    objectHit = this.hitTestObject(_root.killGun);

    if(!objectHit) {
        if (reachedGoal == true)
        {

            if (goNowhere == true)
            {
                gotoAndStop(1);
            }
            //Boundaries
            if (this.x <= 20)
            {
                goRight = true;
                goNowhere = false;
            }
            if (this.x >= stage.stageWidth - 20)
            {
                goRight = false;
                goNowhere = false;
            }

            if (this.y >= stage.stageHeight - 20)
            {
                yDir = 0
            }

            if (this.y <= 20)
            {
                yDir = 1
            }
        }

        //Intro walk
        if (reachedGoal == false)
        {
            if (this.x < actualRange)
                {
                gotoAndStop(4);
                this.x += 3
            }   

            if (this.x >= actualRange)
            {
                reachedGoal = true;
                gotoAndStop(1);
            }
        }
    }

    if (objetHit)
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        _root.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

You should also remove the `Event.ADDED` listener once the object has been added.

```
    private function beginClass(event:Event):void{
        //defining _root as the document root
        _root = MovieClip(root);
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the rest of the loop is trying to run still?

Try breaking out of the loop after the hit:

```
if (this.hitTestObject(_root.killGun))
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    _root.removeChild(this);
    return;
}
```